# Why Remote Process is not launching from WCF call to Process.Start in interactive mode?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, .net-4.0

I have WCF service which launches the remote process from Process.Start successfully on stand alone machine where this WCF service is hosted/deployed and developed.

I  deployed this as whole service on another machine, and run the service on that machine as well, execute the service on the same code area which launches the process remotely, here it failed, Strange behavior.

I checked the process state stand alone , and launched the process normally, it executed fine and shown the message box inside that process which was written there. BUT when this process launched via WCF call from code, process didn't launched in interactive manner, Task Manager shown the launched process, but its console not shown, nor any message box shown . ANY IDEA ? or WAY AROUND?

Note : This behavior is observed when WCF service deployed completely with all binaries on another machine

Regards
Ehsank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services should generally not have any user interface. The same thing goes for processes that services might start.

It works on your development machine because you are developing/debugging it with a valid, active logged-on user (you). the same is not the case when running as a more traditional service on a normal server.